# How to load/configure IBM Daeja ViewONE in html?

Tags: ibm-cloud, document

All my requirement is to load daeja docviewer in html and running it using jsp file in jboss server
I have tried to load/configure IBM Daeja ViewONE using Html.I have included necessary jars and license files but it is not loading. Please help in resolving this and check i need to add/remove any thing to get this running

Jars added

[image: Jars included for Daeja viewer]

Html :

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
   pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
      <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="viewone.js"></script>
      <title>User Data</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div>
         <Object class="com.ibm.dv.client.Viewer" id="viewone" width="100%" height="100%" name="viewone">
            <param name="trace" value="true">
            <param name="tracenet" value="true">
            <param name="tracefilter" value="true">
         </Object>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

``

viewone.js

```
    function ViewOneBootstrap() { alert('1ds1');
    this.logMessages = new Array();
    this.debugMessages = new Array();
    this.clientids = new Array();

    this.codebase = null;
    this.lastFocussed = null;
    this.objectTag = "com.ibm.dv.client.Viewer";
    this.instanceId = 1;

    //document content clipboard
    this.clipboard = new ViewOneClipboard();

    this.getInstanceId = function() {
        return "" + this.instanceId++;
    }
    this.addMessage = function(message) {
        this.logMessages.push(message);
        this.log(message)
    };

    this.clearMessages = function() {
        this.logMessages = new Array();
    };

    this.log = function(message) {
        if (this.debugMessages.length >= 100)
            this.debugMessages.shift();
        this.debugMessages.push(message);
        if (window.console) {
            if (window.console.debug)
                window.console.debug(message);
            else if (window.console.log)
                window.console.log(message);
        }
    };

    this.getHead = function() {
        var headElem = null;
        var oHead = document.getElementsByTagName('head');
        if (oHead == null || oHead.length == 0) {
            headElem = document.createElement();
            document.appendChild(headElem);
        } else {
            headElem = oHead[0];
        }
        return headElem;
    };

    this.includeJS = function(sId, fileUrl, source) {
        viewoneLoader.addMessage("Attaching script " + sId
                + (source == null ? "" : (" length=" + source.length)));
        if ((source != null) && (!document.getElementById(sId))) {
            var oHead = viewoneLoader.getHead();
            var oScript = document.createElement("script");
            oScript.type = "text/javascript";
            oScript.id = sId;
            oScript.defer = "true";

            if (source == null) {
                oScript.src = fileUrl;
            } else {
                oScript.text = source;
            }
            viewoneLoader.getHead().appendChild(oScript);
            viewoneLoader.addMessage("Script attached");
        }
    };

    var addMessage = this.addMessage;
    this.addMessage('ViewOneBootstrap:init<>');

    this.showMessages = function() {
        var messages = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < this.logMessages.length; i++) {
            messages += this.logMessages[i];
            messages += "\n";
        }
        alert(messages);
    };

    this.getHttpRequest = function() {

        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
            return new XMLHttpRequest();
        if (window.ActiveXObject)
            return new ActiveXObject("MsXml2.XmlHttp");
    };

    this.loadScript = function(sId, url, postData) {
        this.codebase = url;
        this.postData = postData;
        this.addMessage('ViewOneBootstrap.loadScript:  ' + url);

        var oXmlHttp = this.getHttpRequest();
        var scriptLoad = this.includeJS;
        var loadFailed = this.loadError;

        oXmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (oXmlHttp.readyState == 4) {
                if (oXmlHttp.status == 200 || oXmlHttp.status == 304) {
                    viewoneLoader.addMessage("Script downloaded");
                    scriptLoad(sId, url, oXmlHttp.responseText);
                } else {
                    var isCrossDomain = true;
                    if (url.indexOf("http://") != 0 && url.indexOf("https://") != 0)
                        isCrossDomain = false;
                        // Can't be cross domain unless the URL starts http: or https:
                    else if (url.indexOf("https:") == 0 && window.location.protocol != "https:")
                        isCrossDomain = false;
                    else if (url.indexOf("http:") == 0 && window.location.protocol != "http:")
                        isCrossDomain = false;
                    else {

                        var url2 = url.replace(/^https?:\/\//, "");
                        var match = url2.match(/^[^\/]+/);
                        if (match) {
                            var domain = match[0];
                            if (window.location.host == domain)
                                isCrossDomain = false;
                        }
                    }
                    if (isCrossDomain && oXmlHttp.status == 0) {  
                        loadFailed("Cannot load ViewONE.\n"
                                + "Likely reasons include:\n"
                                + "- Cross domain resource loading is not supported by this browser\n"
                                + "- Cross domain resource loading is not configured correctly on the server\n"
                                + "- There was a temporary network issue when loading ViewONE\n"
                                + "- This web browser has incorrectly cached some data (please empty the cache)");
                    } else {alert('error 2');
                        viewoneLoader.addMessage('XML request error: '
                                + oXmlHttp.statusText + ' (' + oXmlHttp.status
                                + ')');
                        viewoneLoader.showMessages();
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        oXmlHttp.open('GET', url, true);
        if (oXmlHttp.setRequestHeader)
            oXmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        oXmlHttp.send(null);
    };

    this.includeJS = function(sId, fileUrl, source) {
        viewoneLoader.addMessage("Attaching script " + sId
                + (source == null ? "" : (" length=" + source.length)));
        if (!(source == null && fileUrl == null)
                && (!document.getElementById(sId))) {
            var oHead = viewoneLoader.getHead();
            var oScript = document.createElement("script");
            oScript.type = "text/javascript";
            oScript.id = sId;
            oScript.defer = "true";

            if (source == null) {
                oScript.src = fileUrl;
            } else {
                oScript.text = source;
            }
            oHead.appendChild(oScript);
            viewoneLoader.addMessage("Script attached");
        }
    };

    this.addMetaTag = function(name, content) {
        this.addMessage('ViewOneBootstrap.addMetaTag');
        var oHead = this.getHead();
        var mTag = document.createElement("meta");
        mTag.name = name;
        mTag.content = content;
        oHead.appendChild(mTag);
    };

    this.loadCompleted = function() {
        this.addMessage("ViewOneBootstrap.loadCompleted:  viewer ready to start");

        if (window.notifyViewONECodeInit)
        {
            window.notifyViewONECodeInit();
        }
    };

    this.loadError = function(message) {
        addMessage(message);
        if (window.deinitPercentage) {
            window.deinitPercentage();
            addMessage("Percentage display removed");
        }
        if (window.showViewoneLoadError)
            window.showViewoneLoadError(message);
        else
            alert(message);
    }
}

function ViewOneClipboard() {
    this.content = null;

    this.putContent = function(jsonBlob) 
    {
        //viewoneLoader.log("added to clipboard: " + jsonBlob);
        this.content = jsonBlob;
    }

    this.getContent = function()
    {
        //viewoneLoader.log("retrieved from clipboard: "+ this.content);
        return this.content;
    }
}
 var viewoneLoader = new ViewOneBootstrap();
//viewoneLoader.addMetaTag('viewone_ajax::gwt:property', 'baseUrl=filenet/v1files/?v=9001&op=resource&file=');
//viewoneLoader.loadScript('viewoneLoader', 'filenet/v1files/?v=9001&op=resource&file=viewone.cache.js', '');

viewoneLoader.com_viewone_instance = '1';
viewoneLoader.com_viewone_instancel = {"start":"","end":"","num":"", "modInf": [{"type":"2"}, {"type":"3"}, {"type":"4"}, {"type":"5"}, {"type":"6"}, {"type":"8"}, {"type":"G"}, {"type":"I"}, {"type":"M"}],"trial":false,"company":"","country":"","support":false,"contact":"","rProduct":"","rCompany":"","rEmail":"","rSite":"","rAllowIgnorePro":false,"testBuild":false,"legacyFeatures":false};

viewoneLoader.loadingMessage = 'IBM Daeja ViewONE Virtual 5.0.3';
viewoneLoader.version = "9001";
viewoneLoader.displayversion = "5.0.3";
viewoneLoader.fulldisplayversion = "5.0.3 iFix 1";
viewoneLoader.acceptLanguages = ["en-US","en"];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you remove DIV tags around Daeja object, the page will get loaded. 
If you want to keep the DIV, you need to change width and height value from percentage to absolute px value. Otherwise it won't work. Don't know why and really don't like the way it is.